# Hidden Pagination summary text

Tags: yii, yii-components, yii-events

I use CGridView in Yii to create tables.

I would like to show my table with pagination but hide the summary text at the top, which indicates the number of page restance (Displaying 1-4 of 4 results.)

Is that possible?
thank you

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `template` option. By default it equals `{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}`

If you override it in your gridview config, you'l be able to remove summary section:

```
$this->widget(
                'zii.widgets.CGridView',
                array(
                    Your options here ...
                    'template' => '{items}\n{pager}',
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to set the `CGridView` `summaryText` value to false

Answer (score 1):

Because YII uses CListView, it also add a certain summary class CSS in the asset folder. So to combat this, simply override the css.

Add this to your CSS.

```
#yw0>.summary{ 
    display:none;
}
```