# How to hide the pagination text from clistview detail page?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

How can I hide this pagination text from clistview detail page?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978000/hidden-pagination-summary-text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <?php
      $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'summaryText'=>'',
        'itemView'=>'_view',
           )); 
      ?>
```

you can set this:

```
      'summaryText'=>'',
```